# How can I select a record line from a file using SED

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

`Apologies... Code that I shared earlier is incorrect, revising...`

**Revised Question:**

First of all, I would like to apologize for the rush, I am new in QSHELL and just started learning.. But I badly need your help as I need to integrate the following to my program as soon as possible..

Basically the scenario is, a text file containing invalid/special characters was uploaded into
our server and my program must remove them before processing.

so for example, I have uploadfile.txt and it contains below.

[image]

To replace the special characters I am using the following command and it works fine.

`sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9&,-]/ /g' uploadfile.txt > outputfile.txt`

1. `a to z` lowercase (a-z)
2. `A to Z` uppercase (A-Z)
3. `0-9`
4. `&` Ampersand
5. `,` Comma
6. `.` Period

However, before replacing I need to extract the lines for reporting/communication purposes and I am not quite sure how and got stuck... Tried to search however I still cant get it and I am running out of time..

So my question is, **How can I extract line numbers 2, 4, 5 into a separate text.file?**

Thanks in advance.

**This has been resolved**, I used below command as suggested by @adminbee in the comments.

`sed -n '/[^[:print:]]/p' IFS/MM4R5FLR/S06013/myfile.POL > myfile.pol`
Thank you everyone for the help.

Comment: I don't understand how that grep command is supposed to do what you want. It looks to me more that it actually searches for the lines containing those characters followed by 'p' and printing also the line numbers of the lines that matched.

Comment: Can you edit your post to provide (possibly anonymized) sample input together with corresponding desired output? As stated by @seshoumara, your `grep` call may not produce error messages, but certainly does not do what you intend it to do (notice that in addition, the `.` is not mentioned in your RegExp). Also, are you interested in _any_ solution (including fixing the `grep` call) or does it need to be a `sed`-based solution?

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry... The post has been edited.
I am open for any solution and will try to integrate it to my program, hopefully it will work to my platform. Thanks again.

Comment: `grep $character uploadfile.txt`, replace `$character` with the value of the control character (probably `\x1C`).

Comment: Is a two-step approach viable, i.e. first do a `grep '[^a-zA-Z0-9&,-]' > invalid_lines.txt`, to print all lines with illegal characters to a file, and then perform your replacement `sed` call? Also, the "space" seems not to be on the list of allowed characters, are you sure there (it wouldn't matter in your purging command as you replace illegal characters with space, but it would for the "reporting" command)?

Comment: Thanks for your responses.. 

Hi @AdminBee, tried `grep '/[^a-zA-Z0-9&,-]/' > invalid_lines.txt`, however it is not working :( no output on invalid_lines.txt, I am working on AS400 machine so I am not sure if its the platform... Do u have other solutions?

Yes its fine to have two step approach or more than..
Regarding [space], i think I am good... the output from my 
`sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9&,-]/ /g' uploadfile.txt > outputfile.txt` command looks good to me...

Comment: @user3490590 yeah sorry btw, did you notice I exchanged my comment? The `grep` line I originally posted and that you unfortunately used has a typo in it - the `/ ... /` around the regular expression is wrong, please try the corrected one. As for the space: it would not matter in the replacement since you replace illegal characters with a space, so even if the space is considered illegal, the file de facto wouldn't change. For the "reporting" command however it does make a difference ...

Comment: @AdminBee, tried the updated grep command `grep '[^a-zA-Z0-9&,-]'` however its getting all the lines.. :(

Comment: What happens if you include the space in the character list, as in `grep '[^a-zA-Z0-9&,. -]'`? These lines do, after all, contain spaces. BTW, if your `grep` and `sed` understand POSIX character classes, you may be able to use `[^[:print:]]` to match all "non-printable" characters ...

Comment: Thank you very much @AdminBee, `[^[:print:]]` worked! 
I appreciate other response as well, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: If that's ok for you, I will post is as answer, then.

Comment: yes, please post it as answer.. thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a two-stage approach is ok, then you could first use `grep` to extract all lines with illegal characters into a file, and then use your `sed` command to do the actual replacement.

Note that since your intention is to get rid of special (i.e. "non-printable" characters), you might try using the POSIX character class `[:print:]` instead of enumerating the characters, if your `grep`/`sed` understands these.

So, you could first use

```
grep '[^[:print:]]' uploadfile.txt > invalid_lines.txt
```

to extract all lines with illegal characters for archival purposes, and then perform

```
sed -e 's/[^[:print:]]/ /g' uploadfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

or, if you are absolutely sure, perform an in-place edit via

```
sed -i -e 's/[^[:print:]]/ /g' uploadfile.txt
```

to purge them from the file.

Answer (score 0):

From the [sed docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses) ("selecting lines by text matching"), you can select the lines just the same:

```
# First, report lines
sed -n '/[^a-zA-Z0-9&,-]/p' uploadfile.txt > reportfile.txt

# Then, correct and output text
sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9&,-]/ /g' uploadfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

where the `-n` option will output nothing but what it's printed by the 'p' command, that is, the whole lines selected by the very regular expression of yours.

Comment: Hi @Alan, tried this `sed -n '/[^a-zA-Z0-9&,-]/p' uploadfile.txt > reportfile.txt` however it is extracting all lines.